# Select query to get fields within JSON in orientdb

Tags: json, database, select, orientdb

In what way can I get fields within a JSON that is stored as a OrientDB Class field?

For example,
I have a class FILE having a field named 'data'.

```
orientdb {db=baasbox}> select data from FILE   
----+----------------------  
#   |       data  
----+----------------------  
0   | {"email":"my@domain.com"}  
----+----------------------
```

The field 'data'  is a JSON and I want to get the "email" field: using something like this:

```
orientdb {db=baasbox}> select data.email from FILE   
----+----------------------  
#   |       data.email  
----+----------------------  
0   |     my@domain.com  
----+----------------------
```

This above sql doesn't work and gives this error: `SEVE Error on reading rid with value '[{"email":"my@domain.com"}]' [OSQLMethodField]`

I already tried giving `data.email`, `data[email]`, `data['email']` in the projection, but in vain.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you defined data field as String when it should be Embedded. Try the following.

```
create class File

create property File.data EMBEDDED

insert into File set data = {"email":"my@domain.com"}  

select data.email from File
```

**UPDATE:**

For OrientDB versions prior to 2.0:

```
create class File
create property File.data EMBEDDED
insert into File set data = {"@type":"d", "email":"my@domain.com"} 
select data.email from File
```

Comment: Didn't work. 
orientdb {db=mydb}> insert into file set data = {"email":"my@domain.com"}

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.insert into file set data = {"email":"my@domain.com"}

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OValidationException: The field 'file.data' has been declared as EMBEDDED but an incompatible type is used. Value: {email=my@domain.com}

Comment: Can you please provide the reference to the documentation which explains this?

Comment: I got it to work!! **But** it required the property 'data' not to have any type (embedded). That is, on removing the command 'create property File.data EMBEDDED', it started working. Can you remove it from your post so that I can approve it?

Comment: Done :) But it should work. From 2.0 onwards '@type' and '@class' are not demanded (see [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3398)). Which version of OrientDB you're using?

Comment: It's orientDB 1.7.10. I don't understand how '@type' and '@class' are related to not using the 'create property' command.

Comment: declaring the property as EMBEDDED for orientdb versions prior to 2.0, doesn't work with the Document API. I get the same error when I try to save() the ODocument.

Comment: Can you provide a piece of code that demonstrates the problem?